# How to run selenium python script on already opened chrome?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I know how to open a new window using selenium. But I want a new tab in the same window of chrome which I am using. How to do that?

I already try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9014')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'button')
button.click()
finally:
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You want to open a new tab using selenium, then you can use `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') `

Comment: I want to run the selenium python script on the already opened window

Comment: Will you please refer me an example, like your script is working on an page and you want to open new tab or you want to open new tab when you have chrome opened already and freshly running your script?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the opening/closing of a tab by the combination of keys:
`Ctrl + T` or `Ctrl + W`

You can trigger this shortcut on body of the page, to open new tab within the window, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

#open tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
# You can use (Keys.CONTROL + 't') on other OSs

# Load a page 
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
# Make the tests...

# close the tab
# (Keys.CONTROL + 'w') on other OSs.
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w') 


driver.close()
```

I hope this solves your problem.